# Update JSON file properties with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to update test.json file with a Python script. I only need to change the property of `"plan2"->"2"->"rooms"` to 3. Could you please help me with this?
Thank you very much

test.json

```
{
"plan1" : [{
      "1": {
      "rooms":"2",
      "bathrooms":"1",
      "kitchens":"1"
      },

      "2": {
      "rooms":"1",
      "bathrooms":"1",
      "kitchens":"1"
      }
}],
"plan2":[{
      "1": {
      "rooms":"3",
      "bathrooms":"1",
      "kitchens":"1"
      },

      "2": {
      "rooms":"1",
      "bathrooms":"1",
      "kitchens":"1"
      }
}]
}
```

test.py

```
import json

with open("test.json", "r+") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)

    # need to change the "plan2"->"apartments"->"2"->"rooms" to 3 

    jsonFile.seek(0)  # rewind
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
    jsonFile.truncate()
```

Comment: Yes,it works! Thanks so much, But in my actual test.json there is another `"id" : plan2. I modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

with open("test.json", "r+") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)

    # The change
    d['plan2'][0]['1']['rooms'] = 3

    jsonFile.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
    jsonFile.truncate()
```

Comment: It should be `data['apartments'][0]['2']['rooms'] = 3` as mentioned: `"apartments"->"2"->"rooms"`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add a part of the json file. Could you please modify the answer? Thanks so much

Comment: @brabbit640 Can you please update on which `plan` you want to change the `rooms` value.

Comment: @bumblebee. Done!

Comment: @brabbit640 I think there is a problem with the `json` data. With your `json` there is duplicate `id` key. Maintain it as a `json array`.

Comment: @bumblebee, yeah! corrected it now. Thanks for the help +1 :)

Comment: @brabbit640 Updated the answer.

Comment: @brabbit640 Glad, I could help!.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying an in-memory data structure, not the file itself. To be completely safe, do this in four steps:

1. Read the file into memory
2. Make the changes to your data structure
3. Write the changes back to a *new* file
4. After the write successfully completes, replace the old file with the new.

Putting it together,

```
import json
import tempfile

with open("test.json") as f:
    data = json.loa(f)

data['apartments'][0]['2'][rooms] = 3

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
    os.rename(f.name, "test.json")
```

This assumes that your temporary directory is on the same file system as your JSON file, so that the `rename` operation is atomic. If that is not the case, use the `dir` argument to `NamedTempfile` to specify a directory that *is* on the same file system.

Comment: Really sorry I missed a part in my json file :( Could you please modify the answer. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Not a python answer, but if you have [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) available on your system, you can use this:

```
jq '.plan2[]."2".rooms="3"' test.json
```

[Demo on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/I_IGI7YSdq)